# How to derieve value from intermediate XML variable using XSLT ?

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

**XSLT :**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:variable name="A"  select="$B" /> <!-- B is derived and has xml strucure   --> 
   <!-- how to derive value of elent D here  ???? --> 
   <xsl:variable name="varD"  select="$B/B/C/D" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML :**

```
<B>
  <C>
    <D>xxxx</D>
  </C>  
</B>
```

How to derive value for variable D from variable A ?

Comment: Should `varD` be `$A/B/C/D` instead of `$B/`?  Can you show the definition of variable `B`, and say what version of XSLT you are working with?

Comment: XSLTversion is 1.0 and var B is a xml node/snippet derived dynamically. i.e  var B is similar to <B><C><D>xxx</D></C></B>

Comment: Please show us the code defining the variable `B`, we need to see whether it merely selects nodes in the input document or is a result tree fragment.

Comment: B is exsl:node-set($M)/headers/*  . again M is some big xml tree

Comment: <xsl:variable name="A" select="exsl:node-set($M)/headers/*" />  Now I want to fetch some elements from A.

Comment: Given that definition you can freely use XPaths rooted at A e.g. `$A/foo/bar` or `$A[some-predicate]`.  What _exactly_ is the problem?  What does your input XML look like, what output do you need, and how does what you're currently getting differ from what you want?

Answer (score 0):

It would really help if you showed more of your code so we could see what the real problem is, but I suspect you are hitting the "result tree fragment" issue in XSLT 1.0.

The solution is either to convert your result tree fragment variable into a node-set using the exslt:node-set() extension function, or to move to XSLT 2.0 which removes this problem.